# Debian duplicate file with '~' appended

Tags: linux, debian

So when I list contents of this directory I see a duplicate file with a ~ appended. Picture attached. Can I remove this?

[image: duplicate file]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a backup file created by an editor. Yes, you can remove it.